# MySqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb-10.4

I am using MySql.Data version 8.0.22 on IIS/Windows to try and connect to MariaDB 10.4.12 (Linux).  I am trying to use MySqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters to fetch parameter information:

```
        cmd.CommandText = "Mail_SaveEvent";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        MySqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
```

My stored proc/routine has the following parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE shopmail_test.Mail_SaveEvent(
    IN inEventTypeID int,
    IN inEventDate datetime,
    IN inEventServer int,
    IN inEventTitle varchar(250),
    IN inEventText text,
    IN inEventMerchantID int,
    IN inEventAuditText text,
    IN inEventID int)
  SQL SECURITY INVOKER
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
```

I thought this might be a collation issue (I am using utf8 with utf8_unicode_ci collation), so I commented out all of the text parameters and even removed most of the logic from the body of the routine but I am still getting the following error:

```
12/4/2020 11:20 AM][Production  ]:          Specified cast is not valid.
[12/4/2020 11:20 AM][Production  ]:            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(MySqlCommand command)
```

What's interesting is that if I try and hit this same schema/routine on MariaDB 10.4.17 hosted on a Windows box that the command is populated without any errors.

[image]

This is driving me nuts!  Has anyone experienced this and found out how to fix it?

Comment: Can you try it with MySqlConnector?  MySql.Data has some bugs that MySqlConnector never implemented, so it might work. And even if it doesn't, there's a chance you'll get a better error message.

Comment: I will give that a shot and let you know how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: Wow... no errors :P  That worked great!  Thanks!

Comment: That's great news! Thank [Bradley Grainger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23633/bradley-grainger) and team for making a better library from scratch.

Comment: If you want to write that up as the answer I will totally upvote it.  I looked around to see if Oracle published the source for their library, but no bueno.  I was curious to see if they were just jackin' with me because I was using MariaDB (weird though that I didn't have issues when the DB was hosted on Windows though).

Comment: FYI, MySql.Data source is at https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/tree/8.0 but it's just a periodic code dump of Oracle's internal sources; it's not an active OSS community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bug in MySql.Data (although I don't yet see a relevant report at https://bugs.mysql.com/). You could report it there, and hope that Oracle fixes it in a future version.

Alternatively, switch to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) (disclaimer: lead author), which [fixes a lot of MySql.Data bugs](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs) and has great compatibility with MariaDB.

Comment: Great library, man!  Thanks for all your work!